# 2D point to 3D transformation(using Kinect) programmed by openCV

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

enter code here I am working on something related to 2D point to 3D transformation, which is new to me. Could anyone provide me an outline about doing this? better with explanation. Thank you!

**

```
I solved this problem.
1. read rgb image and depth image from kinect approximately, using http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime.
2. get the formula to calculate the value(x,y) from rgb image and z from depth image into 3D point.x, point.y, point.z
```

**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210822/2d-point-to-3d-transformation(using-kinect)-programmed-by-opencv/) by [fei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22709/fei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend taking a look at the [/tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) wiki page and learning how the ROS handles transforms.  You can also take a look at [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6556373) to learn a bit more detail than the wiki page provides.

Finally, you can take a look at Introduction to Autonomous Mobile Robots by Roland Siegwart and Illah R. Nourbakhsh.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0